# download all pdf's files from server, without access to the main page - only to files

Tags: python, pdf, download

the files names are not random, but they are not in one order (in this case I could use IDM)

for example:

https://din-online.info/pdf is the main page of files and accessible only to Admin apparently.

the files are:

```
https://din-online.info/pdf/mmd12.pdf 
https://din-online.info/pdf/mmd11.pdf 
https://din-online.info/pdf/jm38.pdf 
https://din-online.info/pdf/jm37.pdf
```

so there is order, but there are many Titles and some hard cases like:

```
https://din-online.info/pdf/dorot25-2.pdf 
https://din-online.info/pdf/dorot25-2e.pdf
```

I have been told that python script might do trick, so if someone could give me some advice about it, thanks

Comment: Python is not a magician to do the tricks. You have to know the file names or to have access to list the directory `.../pdf/` on the server. Or any other source with the names that will be used.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

For python, you can programmatically download file given the url using something like

```
import os
import urllib.request

# directory where file will be saved
save_dir = 'downloads'

def download_file(file_url):
    local_save = os.path.join(save_dir, file_url.split('/')[-1])
    try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(file_url, local_save)
    except:
        # catch case where file doesn't exist
        pass
```

If you know the format of the file names in that directory, you can brute force through all possible combinations and attempt to download them. Below is one example for generating possible file names from the examples you gave

```
import itertools
from string import ascii_lowercase
def generate_possible_filenames(url_prefix):
    # potential filename formats:
    # <alphabetic prefix><num suffix>.pdf
    # <alphabetic prefix><num suffix>-<num2 suffix>.pdf
    # <alphabetic prefix><num suffix>-<num2 suffix><alphabetic postfix>.pdf
    alphabetic_prefix_max_length = 3
    num_suffix_max = 99
    num2_suffx_max = 99
    combinations = []

    alphabetic_prefix = []
    for i in range(1, alphabetic_prefix_max_length + 1):
        alphabetic_prefix += ["".join(a) for a in itertools.product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=i)]

    prefixes = [p + str(i) for p in alphabetic_prefix for i in range(num_suffix_max + 1)]
    for p in prefixes:
        print(p + ".pdf")
        download_file(url_prefix + p + ".pdf")
    combinations += [p + ".pdf" for p in prefixes]
    prefixes = [p + '-' + str(i) for p in prefixes for i in range(num2_suffx_max + 1)]
    for p in prefixes:
        print(p + ".pdf")
        download_file(url_prefix + p + ".pdf")
    prefixes = [p + c for p in prefixes for c in ascii_lowercase]
    for p in prefixes:
        print(p + ".pdf")
        download_file(url_prefix + p + ".pdf")

generate_possible_filenames("https://din-online.info/pdf/")
```